# $in query with $elemMatch in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb-query

I need to find a document where "components" not exist OR if exists, its id is 1111 and isActive is true and "issues" not exist OR its id is 1111 and isActive is true.

Example:
Document 1: ////this contains "components" but not "issues"

```
{..
 "components" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "1111",
            "name" : "component1",
            "isActive" : true
        }
    ],
}
```

Document 2://this contains "issues" but not "components"

```
{..
 "issues" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "1111",
            "name" : "issue 1",
            "isActive" : true
        }
    ],
..}
```

Document 3://This is not having both

Query:

```
    db.sample.find({
    "issues":{$in:[null, {"$elemMatch" : {"id":"1111","isActive": {"$in":[true,null]}}}]},
    "components":{$in:[null, {"$elemMatch" : {"id":"1111","isActive": {"$in":[true,null]}}}]}
})
```

But I am getting an error, "errmsg" : "cannot nest $ under $in",

Please help to form the query that returns all the above 3 documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't require `$in`. You need `$or` operator.

Try

```
db.sample.find({
 $or:[
    {"issues":{$exists:true,"$elemMatch" : {"id":"1111","isActive": true}}},
    {"components":{$exists:true,"$elemMatch" : {"id":"1111","isActive": true}}}
  ]
})
```

Based on OP's comments. here is the working version.

```
db.Sample.find({ 
 $or:[
   {"issues":{$exists:true,"$elemMatch":{"id":"1111","isActive":true}},
     "components":{$exists:false} },
   {"components":{$exists:true,"$elemMatch":{"id":"1111","isActive":true}}, 
     "issues":{$exists:false}}, 
   {"issues":{$exists:true,"$elemMatch":{"id":"1111","isActive": true}}, 
    "components":{$exists:true,"$elemMatch":{"id":"1111","isActive":true}}}, 
   {"issues":{$exists:false}, "components":{$exists:false}} 
 ] 
})
```

Comment: your query will return documents which is having some other id (Eg: issues.id = 1111 , components.id = 2232), this is not expected.

Comment: Try `db.sample.find( 
{"issues":{$exists:true,"$elemMatch" : {"id":"1111","isActive": true}}, "components":{$exists:true,"$elemMatch" : {"id":"1111","isActive": true}}}`
 )

Comment: This will not return any of the 3 Documents pointed in my question.

Comment: db.sample.find({$and:[
    {$or:[{"issues" : {"$elemMatch" : {"id":"1111","isActive": true}}},{"issues" : null}]},
    {$or:[{"components" : {"$elemMatch" : {"id":"1111","isActive": true}}},{"components" : null}]}
    ]}) - this is working in roboMongo, but throwing exception in java, saying wrong top level operator. So expecting a query something like this

Comment: Try `db.col.find({
 $or:[
    {"issues":{$exists:true,"$elemMatch" : {"id":"1111","isActive": true}},"components":{$exists:false} },
    {"components":{$exists:true,"$elemMatch" : {"id":"1111","isActive": true}}, "issues":{$exists:false}},
    {"issues":{$exists:true,"$elemMatch" : {"id":"1111","isActive": true}}, "components":{$exists:true,"$elemMatch" : {"id":"1111","isActive": true}}} 
  ]
})` . This will also include the document where components and issues both match the criteria.

Comment: This is returning first two documents, but not the 3rd document which is not having both "issues" and "components"

Comment: Just add one more condition to the or and you should be fine.

Comment: I think we can shorten it but for now this should work. `db.col.find({ $or:[ {"issues":{$exists:true,"$elemMatch" : {"id":"1111","isActive": true}},"components":{$exists:false} }, {"components":{$exists:true,"$elemMatch" : {"id":"1111","isActive": true}}, "issues":{$exists:false}}, {"issues":{$exists:true,"$elemMatch" : {"id":"1111","isActive": true}}, "components":{$exists:true,"$elemMatch" : {"id":"1111","isActive": true}}}, {"issues":{$exists:false},"components":{$exists:false}}  ] })`

Comment: Nope. You are checking for exists:true or exists:false... This is not returning anything

Comment: are you sure ? it works for me. the last condition is both false which is your third document no ?

Comment: Yes. I have a document with - "components" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "1111",
            "name" : "component1",
            "isActive" : true
        }  -- This is not being returned

Comment: I am getting 0 records fetched for the below command, 
db.Sample.find({ $or:[ {"issues":{$exists:true,"$elemMatch" : {"id":"1111","isActive": true}},
"components":{$exists:false} }, {"components":{$exists:true,"$elemMatch" : {"id":"1111","isActive": true}}, 
"issues":{$exists:false}}, {"issues":{$exists:true,"$elemMatch" : {"id":"1111","isActive": true}}, 
"components":{$exists:true,"$elemMatch" : {"id":"1111","isActive": true}}}, {"issues":{$exists:false},
"components":{$exists:false}} ] }) -- Thanks though, for your quick comments

Comment: Is your collection name Sample or sample ?