# filter out MongoDB documents based on attributes in an array of objects

Tags: mongodb

We have mongoDB documents representing tasks. Each task contains a list of required skills, and a numeric minimum level for each skill. A person is able to process a task if he has all the required skills with a sufficient level for each.

Task example:

```
{
  required_skills: [
    {_id: "skill_A", level: 5},
    {_id: "skill_B", level: 2}
  ]
}
```

A person with skills `[{_id: "skill_A", level: 5},{_id: "skill_B", level: 2}]` will be able to process tasks with required_skills:

- `[{_id: "skill_A", level: 4},{_id: "skill_B", level: 2}]`
- `[{_id: "skill_A", level: 5}]`
- `[{_id: "skill_B", level: 1}]`

but not tasks with required_skills:

- `[{_id: "skill_A", level: 4},{_id: "skill_B", level: 2},{_id: "skill_C", level: 2}]`  // missing skill_C
- `[{_id: "skill_A", level: 6},{_id: "skill_B", level: 2}]`  // insufficient level on Skill_A

We need a mongo query to be able to find all tasks that are acceptable for a person with given skills. The person skills list will be a parameter of the query.

For performance reasons, we would like to avoid javascript functions in Mongo as well as an incomplete filter which would force us to do some post-processing in java to eliminate irrelevant tasks.

We are looking for something like:

```
for each task in collection:
  for each skill in task's skills:
   - if skill._id is not in the person's skills, filter out the task
   - if skill.level is greater than the corresponding skill level of the person, filter out the task

return remaining tasks
```

So far we tried:

```
{
   "$or":[
      {
         "skills":{
            "$elemMatch":{
               "_id":{
                  "$eq":"skill-2"
               },
               "level":{
                  "$lte":3
               }}}
      },
      {
         "skills":{
            "$elemMatch":{
               "_id":{
                  "$eq":"skill-1"
               },
               "level":{
                  "$lte":3
               }}}}
   ]
}
```

but with this query a task matches as soon as one of its skills is acceptable. Meaning that the java client application has to implement a second filter to eliminate irrelevant tasks

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have the actual data, the code is not actually tested. But this might work:

```js
const searchParams = [
    {required_skills:{ $elemMatch: { _id: "Skill_A", level: { $lte: 5 } } }},
    {required_skills:{ $elemMatch: { _id: "Skill_B", level: { $lte: 2 } } }},
    {required_skills:{ $elemMatch: { _id: "Skill_C", level: { $lte: 8 } } }},
]

const tasksQualified = await taskDB.find({
        $or: searchParam
})
```

The elements of `searchParams` can be dynamically generated based on your need.

```
searchParams.psuh({ $elemMatch: { _id: "Skill_D", level: { $lte: 3 } } })
```

Also, check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49201811/in-query-with-elemmatch-in-mongodb) as well.

Comment: mongo server (3.6.19) replies with "cannot nest $ under $in". Is it something that is supposed to work in a more recent version?

Comment: I don't think so. It's a syntax error on my side. It is not supported I guess. But check the updated answer. Change `$in` to `$or`, and see if it works.

Comment: $or fails with "unknown operator: $or". Seems that $or clause is not supported as a right hand side criteria

Comment: Check the updated version. `$or` should be a supported top-level operator.

Comment: this is basically what we tried. It works partially but does not filter all irrelevant tasks. For example, a task requiring skill_A AND skill_B will match even if the person only has skill_A

Comment: What if you change the operator to `$and`?

Comment: ```$and``` only matches tasks that have all the skills of the person. We need a task with a unique skill_A to match for a person with skill_A and skill_B